# How to create a two-color, dashed line in Inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape, drawing, line-art

How can I draw a two-color, dashed line in Inkscape?

The only possibility I see is to draw a colored/transparent line.

Comment: Have you tried your proposed method?  What else have you tried?  May we see examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dashed strokes are effectively part stroke and part non-stroke (transparent).

2 possibilities for 2 color stroke:

1. Duplicate the stroke, and group both together. Set the lower stroke in one color, and the upper stroke to dashed style, and another color.
2. Use only 1 stroke, and set the stroke fill to gradient or (custom) pattern.

Comment: You can use the same dash style for both, and use offset on one to make them alternate: https://i.imgur.com/KAY5gXW.png